# Fix width of list item and hide overflowing text

Tags: html, css

I have a list with a single item in it, I want to fix the width of the list item to 200px and have the text link truncate with '...' if it extends beyond the width of 200px.

Any ideas how I might go about doing this?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="account.asp">Super long string</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Put the anchor tag inside a div with fixed width, for example

Comment: @bodi0 he wants the elipsis too - not just truncated

Answer (score 4):

```
ul li {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use this css:

```
ul li {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This css style is the key:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Play with it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

Tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/xXM2z/